# Can you crack my cipher?

Tags: cipher

Can you crack this cipher of mine?
Each 6×6 box is a word; therefore there are 26 words. All words are English. The text is read left to right, top to bottom. As might be guessed, the 36 squares per 6×6 box represent one letter or digit 0-9.

> [image: cipher image consisting of a grid of circles and squares - not exactly low-vision friendly]

The link to the blog I created.
https://cipherattempt23-fade.blogspot.com/2020/07/cipherattempt23-fade.html

NOTE: I'VE POSTED 2 HINTS IN ONE ON THE SAME BLOG AS THE LINK ABOVE

Comment: I inserted the image into the puzzle body, and I also removed the second question from the title. It might be best to ask that as a sub-question in the comments here.

Comment: Tod - also, welcome to Puzzling.SE! Reading through [this](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717/46002) might help you understand why people have downvoted this puzzle.

Comment: Is there an error in the box in the second row, fourth column? It is the only one with two open circles.

Comment: I gave this a shot but didn't get anywhere. If anyone else wants to try, here's a transcription of the symbols in each square (in order `OΔ─│┼╲╱╳`, ordering the locations A-Z then 0-9): `D7R1K 4B 83D7NV8 99OC7 NB CTI1K AQQT 4H C6FVU IU 1KLYQTUP H9TOR OA S8 T305 7F PQ68SCRA AQQT 4H C6FVU IU 7W9U 7Q8PKCRD 40 G6U VIV7H`

Comment: It's a serial killing confession. I'm calling the FBI.

Answer (score 3):

Plaintext:

> There is nothing which is secret save it shall be revealed; there is no work of darkness save it shall be made manifest in the light  *(2 Nephi 30:17, Book of Mormon)*

Cipher:

> I solved it as a substitution cipher that is both homophonic (many cipher letters to one plain letter) and polyphonic (many plain letters to one cipher letter). I suspect it is in fact a polyalphabetic cipher, but I haven't figured out the pattern to the use of alphabets.

The grid I ended up with:

> [image: Deciphering grid]